# Hover style is not applied when using IE filter and element cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a clickable overlay to position over arbitrary parts of the page. The overlay is mostly semitransparent but has a portion that is completely opaque hence I cannot simply use the opacity property.

I was able to make it work in all browsers except IE 7 and 8 (I don't care about IE 6).

My solution was simply to make the background semitransparent using rgba and the hover style alters that style. Of course, rgba isn't available in IE prior to 9, so I use filter and -ms-filter with a gradient to achieve the same effect.

The problem is that the element doesn't seem to receive any hover event once the gradient filter is applied since the hover style isn't used and the javascript event isn't called.

Any ideas on how to receive a hover event while using gradient filters in IE?

Here is the style that is applied to the overlay element:

```css
#foo {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(230, 250, 250, .25);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#40B0FAFA', endColorstr='#40B0FAFA')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#40B0FAFA', endColorstr='#40B0FAFA');
    zoom: 1;
}

#foo:hover {
    background-color: rgba(230, 250, 250, 1);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFB0FAFA', endColorstr='#FFB0FAFA')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFB0FAFA', endColorstr='#FFB0FAFA');
}
```

[Here is a simple example of the problem using jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln28K/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a JQuery work around.

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
 $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(230, 250, 250, 1)');
 //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work because the hover event handler functions are never invoked. [See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln28K/4/).

Comment: I am slightly confused about what you are trying to achieve?  In IE, when you mouse over 'click overlay', the background text is hidden.  Is this not what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to achieve, but that doesn't work in IE 9 when in IE 7 or IE 8 document mode. Oh, and I should say that it doesn't work if I simply hover over the overlay as opposed to the 'click overlay'.

Comment: Interesting...if you hover over the overlay (not 'click overlay') it works in IE 8? Did it work before you added the jQuery work around?

Comment: Looks like it did also work before the jQuery workaround for me in IE8. Edit: You might want to play around with document modes.